# Trying to receive access token from OAuth 2.0 via android

Tags: android, android-studio, oauth

following  [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVK1H7_EHK4) I tried to receive Access Token from my company's site but,
I also had to add headers to the POST method and since the author of the tutorial didnt, I had to do this on my own, but im super new to these things and dont know if i did it the right way. And because of that (possibly?) all i get is a 401 response here are all the files from my project : [click me!](https://gist.github.com/MentoSSer)
If anyone could help me, Id be greatful

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [AppAuth-Android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android), and not implementing the authorization flow by yourself, which can be complicated.

> AppAuth for Android is a client SDK for communicating with OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect providers.

AppAuth handles the authorization flow (i.e.  The  `performActionWithFreshTokens()` method handles the token refreshing automatically).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Link is dead, I could not find that codelab anywhere, the code is still on Github but no codelab itself.

Comment: Thanks @David, I've removed the broken link